# Websockets + servant-server

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to make websockets work with servant-server:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds         #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators     #-}

import           Control.Monad.IO.Class
import           Data.Text                (Text)
import           Network.Wai.Handler.Warp (run)
import           Network.WebSockets
import           Servant                  hiding (route)
import           Servant.API.WebSocket

type API = Raw
  :<|> "game" :> WebSocketPending

myAPI :: Proxy API
myAPI = Proxy

server :: Server API
server = serveDirectoryFileServer "site"
  :<|> game "From socket server"

game :: MonadIO m => Text -> PendingConnection -> m ()
game msg pending = do
  conn <- liftIO $ acceptRequest pending
  liftIO $ sendTextData conn msg

app :: Application
app = serve myAPI server

main :: IO ()
main = run 8080 app
```

The intention is to send a string `From socket server` back to a client for testing.

In Firefox console:

```
// Create WebSocket connection.
socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/game');

// Connection opened
socket.addEventListener('open', function (event) {
    socket.send('Hello Server!');
});

// Listen for messages
socket.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
    console.log('Message from server ', event.data);
});
```

I got an error frome firefox:

```
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at ws://localhost:8080/game
```

Could someone give me a hint?

**Update:**

Here's the code that worked after re-ordering the API.

```
type API = "game" :> WebSocketPending
  :<|> Raw

myAPI :: Proxy API
myAPI = Proxy

server :: Server API
server = game
  :<|> serveDirectoryFileServer "site"

game :: MonadIO m => PendingConnection -> m ()
game pending = do
  conn <- liftIO $ acceptRequest pending
  liftIO $ withPingThread conn 30 (return ()) $ do
    forever $ do
      msg <- receiveData conn :: IO Text
      sendTextData conn msg
```

Comment: Apologies for what is probably a daft question, but it's the obvious place to start: are you sure your Haskell app was actually running at the point you ran this in the Firefox console?

Comment: @RobinZigmond Yes it's running. I can access http:localhost:8080

Comment: OK, thanks. The only other thing I can think of is that I think `Raw` "captures" all requests,so the request to `game` is probably getting "intercepted" by your plain HTTP server, rather than the Websocket part. In which case, you just need to change the order in the `API` type and `server` definition. I'm hesitant to say this will work though, as I'm no expert on Servant and it's been a while since I last played with it.

Comment: @RobinZigmond It worked! by switching the orders! Thanks man!

Comment: no problem. Since it worked I'll quickly write it up as an answer, it would be good if you accepted it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turns out to be the order of your API endpoints in the type definition.

The type combinator `(:<|>)` is described in the [docs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-0.18.2/docs/Servant-API.html#t::-60--124--62-), as

> Union of two APIs, first takes precedence in case of overlap.

and since [Raw](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-0.18.2/docs/Servant-API.html#t:Raw) essentially matches everything, your original definition was treating all requests as "raw" requests, never forwarding to your Websocket server.

Simply switching the order - of the arguments to `(:<|>)` in both the type and the `server` definition - fixes this problem, as you observed.